# set fadeOut speed in jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a jquery plugin and I want to set `fadeOut` with user favorite speed.I have this code in my html file :

```
$("div").test({
       fadeOutSpeed:"2"
    })
```

and something like this is my jquery plugin file :

```
    (function($) {
        $.fn.test = function(action) {
            var setting = $.extend({
                fadeOutSpeed: "2",
            }, action);
            this.each(function() {
                var element = $(this);
                element.click(function() {
                    element.slideUp(setting.fadeOutSpeed);
                });
            });
        }
    })(jQuery)
```

It doesn't work and the user can not set a favorite speed for fading out the `div` element.How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Why do you pass the speed as a string? And can you really tell the difference between 2 and 4 milliseconds?

Comment: Based on the usage of that property, I think `slideUpDuration` would be a more appropriate name than `fadeOutSpeed`.

Comment: as @Juhana said, better integer, but jquery understand string as well. probably you cannot see the difference since you pass 4 milliseconds. try to pass 400 and 1000

Comment: @NereoCostacurta It doesn't work with any numbers.I think my code has some algorithmic problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an undefined variable `element` in your script.

If you define the variable, things work just fine:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.test = function(action) {
        var setting = $.extend({
            fadeOutSpeed: "2",
        }, action);
        this.each(function() {
            var element = $(this);
            element.click(function() {
                element.slideUp(setting.fadeOutSpeed);
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Note that the speed in `slideUp` is milliseconds, so you might want to test the script with slower timings, like:

```
$("div").test({
    fadeOutSpeed: 2000
})
```

Comment: I had `var element = $(this)` in my code, but I forgot to write it here.But the second solution works for me.I had a mistake in seconds and milliseconds and when I give the speed in milliseconds, problem solved ! Thanks